# How to select full range in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

When I am debugging a excel-vba program I came to know my data range is not completely selected.

Below picture shows my data's model and my problem.
[image]

I used this code to select the whole range. But this is not working properly.

```
Dim rngTemp As Range
Set rngTemp = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
With rngTemp
```

Please help me by giving the code for selecting the whole range as given in the figure above.

Comment: Try [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba). And then use the similar method to find the last column and then construct your range

Comment: Could you not use Set rngTemp = Cells.usedrange?

Comment: @99moorem: UsedRange is a bad idea as explained in the link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are searching by `xlByRows`. And hence you are getting the address of the last cell which has data which is `G7`.

Further to my comment, Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
            lastcol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            lastrow = 1: lastcol = 1
        End If

        Set rng = .Range("A1:" & _
                         Split(.Cells(, lastcol).Address, "$")(1) & _
                         lastrow)

        MsgBox rng.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE BE AWARE THAT METHOD BELOW IS NOT RELIABLE IN SOME CASES. I WILL LEAVE THIS ANSWER HERE AS A BAD EXAMPLE. FOR DETAILED INFORMATION PLEASE SEE @SiddharthRout 'S EXPLANATION IN THIS [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

I would use following code to find used range instead of looking for "*" in the cell value:

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim aWB As Workbook
    Dim aWS As Worksheet

    Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set aWS = aWB.ActiveSheet '<-You can change sheet name like aWB.sheets("SheetName")

    With aWS.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        LastColumn = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
    End With

    aWS.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select '<---Cells(1, 1) is the starting cell of range)

End Sub
```

Comment: Like I mentioned it to @99moorem, `UsedRange` is a bad idea. You may want to see the link that I posted below the question :D

Comment: Yes I just noticed. Thanks for the heads up. I will quit using this method as of now. Thank you very much.